# Printing Image using ePOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, printing, ios8, epson

I want to print receipt image. I am succesfull to some extend. I am using ePOS SDK from Epson for Printing. Following is code to print Image

```
//create builder
EposBuilder *builder = [[[EposBuilder alloc] initWithPrinterModel:printername_ Lang:language_] autorelease];
if(builder == nil){
    return;
}
//add command
int result = [builder addImage:selectImage_ X:0 Y:0 Width:MIN(IMAGE_WIDTH_MAX, selectImage_.size.width) Height:selectImage_.size.height Color:EPOS_OC_COLOR_1 Mode:[self getBuilderMode] Halftone:[self getBuilderHalftone] Brightness:[self getBuilderBrightness]];
result = [builder addCut:EPOS_OC_CUT_NO_FEED];
if(result != EPOS_OC_SUCCESS){
    [ShowMsg showExceptionEpos:result method:@"addImage"];
    return;
}
else{
    [ShowMsg showExceptionEpos:result method:@"statusmsg_status"];
}
//send builder data
unsigned long status = 0;
unsigned long battery = 0;
result = [printer_ sendData:builder Timeout:SEND_TIMEOUT Status:&status Battery:&battery];

[builder clearCommandBuffer];
```

I am able print it ,

1. alignment of image is not proper
   [image]

Comment: Dude facing same issue...please help someone

Comment: Plz check ePOS sdk forum if any exist. You can ask them for any known issues.

Comment: Any one knows how to print long image data using epson? Actually the image which i pass to printer contains the long data. It looks perfect in UIImage but i am printing it. It cuts from bottom and data start overwrite at last line. Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: you can increase bottom padding .. i had same issue.. i added extra space at bottom

Comment: Hey how can i format this printing data in table format?

Comment: Hello Pawan,i need your help.please reply me for this formatitng of receipt

Comment: @shreenashah to format receipt.convert your receipt view to Image and pass it in printing method.

Comment: @KrutarthPatel I already Did it.

Comment: @shreenashah when i am printing image.print image is so small size than actual image size.can you plz tell

Comment: @KrutarthPatel you can use HTML tag to generate a format for receipt using webview .

Comment: @the1pawan sir did you send me one demo that print receipt on printer ?

Comment: Did you got the solution @the1pawan ?

Comment: Refer demo provided with SDK. This will help to align content in the center.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue when printing data with Thermal Printer.
You should use HTML Formate to make your print better. 
Follow the steps.

1. Create one HTML string.
2. Use complete width of the paper.
3. Load HTML UIWebView+Blocks Files you can search on Google.
4. When it complete load make webview's height as per it's content's height.
5. Now capture screenshot of UIWebView's layer
6. Send that image to printer.

It will help you.
Thanks